# Is it correct to say "soup doesn't go well with fried eggs"?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

We know that "**someone gets along well or gets on well with someone**" they have a good relationship.

How do we express the similar idea when talking about food?

For example, people don't eat soup with fried eggs because the combination of soup and fried eggs does not make a good meal.

I found this in the dictionary

> **go with something**: ​to be included with or as part of something

I am not sure if it is idiomatic to say

-"*soup doesn't go well with fried eggs*"

-"*fried eggs go well with cucumbers or toasts*"

I am not sure if we can say "**soup doesn't suit fried eggs**" but "**suit**" is normally used for clothes.

Is it correct to say "**soup doesn't go well with fried eggs**"?

Comment: 'Suit' is normally used with clothes, but not exclusively. Chili sauce doesn't suit/go well with/go with bubble tea. All your examples are fine.

Comment: Soup and fried eggs simply don't go together. Period.